# Sending images over Python socket, internet speed considerations

Tags: python, sockets, pickle, zlib

I've been trying to send/receive images using Python sockets. The images are basically pygame.Surface obtained from some game logic, have resolution 400x300, 3 bytes each. I can do this on my own system, but my problem is - 400x300x3 bytes = 360000 bytes, and I want to the frame rate to be at least 30 fps, which means that would require internet speed of about 10.8 MBps (Mbytes per second). I know screen sharing uses about 40kbps - 8 Mbps (bits per second) at max, which is significantly less and also at a higher resolution. I tried using zlib for compression, but it could only compress images up to 6 times at max, while also slowing down the program, hence unable to achieve 30fps. So, how would I be able to send images at 8Mbps or less while maintaining 30fps?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You talk about sharing frames, presumably over a local network, then suddenly about Internet (non-local) then suddenly about screen-sharing. How are the 3 things related? What are you actually trying to do? Thank you.

Comment: *"So, how would I be able to send images at 8Mbps or less while maintaining 30fps?"* - use proper compression: don't compress each image separately as with zlib but send only the differences between frames. And maybe use lossy compression instead of lossless. See [RFC 6143](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6143#section-7.7) for some ways done by the remote framebuffer protocol.

Comment: @MarkSetchell you are right, I should have made it clearer. 1) I have already shared frames locally (on my computer), so that is not an issue, just an indicator of my progress so far. 2) I would now like to share it non-locally, which would make internet speed a constraint. 3) I used screen sharing as an example, sort of a gold standard for sharing real time images.

Comment: Still not very clear to me. You have one machine generating frames of 400x300x3 bytes at 30 fps? How many clients are receiving? Are the clients on local network or across Internet? What do the frames look like? Do they differ little such that motion-estimation or frame-differencing could be used? Is JPEG compression acceptable? What have you tried?

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I did try compressing the difference between each frame, but using random numbers. My methodology was to generate 2 sets of 120000 (400x300) random nos. and comparing the time it takes to compress just the frame vs. the time it takes to compress the difference between the 2 sets of random nos. Maybe, I should try it with the images, since they aren't really random. I don't think lossless compression is an option since the resolution is low as it is.

Comment: @UmangLunia: *"... but using random numbers ..."* - The very property of random numbers is that there is no information shared between these numbers. This means that data purely consisting of random number cannot be compressed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell We can assume one client is receiving, because I only care about sending out 1 frame of image per cycle. Since the frames are obtained from game logic, they are only slightly different from the last frame, which is why I thought of using difference between frames, but as I mentioned in the reply to Steffen, for some reason I only tested it on random nos. I'm gonna try it on the actual frames this time and let you know about the results.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich ah that's true. I guess at the moment I was only thinking in lines of 'if getting more no. of zeros' in the info will result in better compression. I just thought I came up with that method (I know I'm stupid), I didn't know if this was a real thing until now. But your comments have made me realize it is an actual thing :D